# How to solve Invalid object name when naming a select/

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I named my query and when I tried use it I got: Invalid object name 'AssetsTenDays'. How do I solve that issue?

```
WITH AssetsTenDays AS(
SELECT DISTINCT top 2 
   a.name,
   ir.number
   FROM install i
   INNER JOIN asset a ON a.pws_assetId = i.pws_AssetId   
   WHERE a.days = 10        
)
```

when I try to use it I get the Invalid object name -

```
SELECT distinct  *
from AssetsTenDays
```

Comment: That's a cte, but you are using it as a view. Do `CREATE VIEW AssetsTenDays  AS SELECT ...` instead, and then you can do `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM AssetsTenDays`.

Comment: A common table expression (CTE, - "WITH" clause) does not create a new object in the database. You have to run both statements as a single statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using them together in a single SQL statement, as such:

```
WITH AssetsTenDays AS(
SELECT DISTINCT top 2 
   a.name,
   ir.number
   FROM install i
   INNER JOIN asset a ON a.pws_assetId = i.pws_AssetId   
   WHERE a.days = 10        
)
SELECT distinct  *
from AssetsTenDays
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expression should be used immediate after declaration :

```
WITH AssetsTenDays AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT top 2 a.name, ir.number
    FROM install i INNER JOIN 
         asset a 
         ON a.pws_assetId = i.pws_AssetId   
    WHERE a.days = 10        
)
SELECT ad.*
FROM AssetsTenDays ad;
```

You can't use other `SELECT` statement  between declaration & calling common table expression. It should immediate called after declaration.